# How to build a proxy controller and faraday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, faraday

I have to built an angular js application as a client to consume the api.
The problem is that the api doesn't support jsonp calls.

So I've created a rails application that makes the calls to the api and returns the content.
I'm using the [faraday gem](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday)

Right now I have a method for each call to the api. But since every method only creates a request, triggers the request and returns the content.

I'm was wandering if I can create a proxy controller that creates the request based on what it receives then creates an request with faraday and returns the result. Something like this :

```
 def proxy_request
    if request.method_symbol == :get || request.method_symbol == :delete
 line 7: response = faraday_conn.run_request(request.method_symbol, request.fullpath, nil, request.headers)
    elsif request.method_symbol == :post || request.method_symbol == :put || request.method_symbol == :patch
  response = faraday_conn.run_request(request.method_symbol, request.fullpath, request.body.read, request.headers)
end

render :text => response.body, :status => response.status, :content_type => response.headers["Content-Type"]
```

end

This is not working. What I'm doing wrong ?
It always fails with

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `strip' for #<StringIO:0x3436848>):
app/controllers/api_proxy_controller.rb:7:in `proxy_request'
```

Comment: I dropped angular tag as JS framework you use to consume data client side is completely irrelevant to issue

Answer (score 0):

The backtrace is incomplete (some frameworks, e.g. Rails/RSpec, may hide lines coming from outside your project by default). The error actually came from `Net::HTTP` (`net/http/header.rb:17`), at least in my case (Ruby 2.1, Rails 4.0.2 and the default Faraday adapter). It expects all values in headers to be strings (or at least respond to `strip`).

One workaround is to exclude any header with a non-string value. Depending on what you want to do, this may or may not work for you, e.g. something like:

```
faraday_conn.run_request(
  request.method_symbol,
  request.fullpath,
  request.body.read,
  request.headers.select{|k,v| v.respond_to?(:strip)}
)
```

Note that, since this is in a Rails controller, `request.headers` returns an instance of `ActionDispatch::Http::Headers` which quacks like a `Hash` but not actually a `Hash` (you can call `to_h` on it to convert it to a hash).